# Include the header on all the pages in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am building a website and I am working with PHP. I have created a file named `header.php` (contains the header that needs to be included on all my page).

Let me use the content of my file `header.php` to explain myself better.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
  <title>Fashion</title>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/header.css"/>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slider.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bloc-page.css"/> <!--Load it when the user is on the page clothes.php-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/footer.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/header-search.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/back-to-top.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form-register.css"> <!--Load it when the user is on the page register.php-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form-login.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style-carousel.css" />  <!--Load it when the user is on shoes.php-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/owl.carousel.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/owl.theme.default.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/form-register.js"></script>
  <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script> <!-- Modernizr -->
 </head>
```

The problem I am facing is that, I want to load certains `CSS` files when I am on certains pages. For example, I want to load the file `bloc-page.css` when the user is on `clothes.php`

I was thinking about using regular expression but I wanted to know if there is a better way of doing that.

Thanks for replying

Comment: Look "if current page php". Plus, (just a suggestion); you shouldn't use `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>` inside that included file, as it stands to generate multiple copies of the same when used with another file that may contain `<!DOCTYPE html>` in turn throwing warnings.

Comment: use if else conditions as per page url

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I only use `<!DOCTYPE html>` in the file `header.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make an array of all nessecary addon-css before you include header.php

```
<?php
$addonCss = Array("bloc-page.css");
include "header.php";
//... rest of page
?>
```

then check if there is such an array in header.php:

```
<?php
//....
if(isset($addonCss)) {
     for($i=0;$i<count($addonCss); $i++) {
         echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/".$addonCss[$i]."\"/>\n";
     }
}
//...
?>
```

This is just one (for here easiest) of many possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Make a base url and insert it all src, like

```
$base_url="mydomain.com";
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $base_url ?>css/header.css"/>
```